# Python : Pandas - ONLY remove NaN rows and move up data, do not move up data in rows with partial NaNs

Tags: python, pandas

Alright, so here is my code that I'm currently drafting to pull all national league players fielding stats. It works fine, however, I am interested in knowing how to drop ONLY lines of NaNs in dataframes without disturbing any of the data:

```
# import libraries
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# create a url object
url = r'https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/NL/2022-standard-fielding.shtml'

# create list of the stats that we care about
standardFieldingStats = [
    'player',
    'team_ID',
    'G',
    'GS',
    'CG',
    'Inn_def',
    'chances',
    'PO',
    'A',
    'E_def',
    'DP_def',
    'fielding_perc',
    'tz_runs_total',
    'tz_runs_total_per_season',
    'bis_runs_total',
    'bis_runs_total_per_season',
    'bis_runs_good_plays',
    'range_factor_per_nine',
    'range_factor_per_game',
    'pos_summary'
]

# Create object page
page = requests.get(url)

# parser-lxml = Change html to Python friendly format
# Obtain page's information
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

# grab each teams current year batting stats and turn it into a dataframe
tableNLFielding = soup.find('table', id='players_players_standard_fielding_fielding')

# grab player UID
puidList = []
rows = tableNLFielding.select('tr')
for row in rows:
    playerUID = row.select_one('td[data-append-csv]')
    playerUID = playerUID.get('data-append-csv')if playerUID else None
    if playerUID == None:
        continue
    else:
        puidList.append(playerUID)

# grab players position
compList = []
for row in rows:
    thingList = []
    for stat in range(len(standardFieldingStats)):
        thing = row.find("td", attrs={"data-stat" : standardFieldingStats[stat]})
        if thing == None:
            continue
        elif row.find("td", attrs={"data-stat" : 'player'}).text == 'Team Totals':
            continue
        elif row.find("td", attrs={"data-stat" : 'player'}).text == 'Rank in 15 NL teams':
            continue
        elif row.find("td", attrs={"data-stat" : 'player'}).text == 'Rank in 15 AL teams':
            continue
        elif thing.text == '':
            continue
        elif thing.text == 'NaN':
            continue
        else:
            thingList.append(thing.text)
    compList.append(thingList)

# insert the batting headers to a dataframe
NLFieldingDf = pd.DataFrame(data=compList, columns=standardFieldingStats)

#NLFieldingDf = NLFieldingDf.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values))

#NLFieldingDf = NLFieldingDf.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.fillna('').values))

# make all NaNs blanks for aesthic reasons
#NLFieldingDf = NLFieldingDf.fillna('')

#NLFieldingDf.insert(loc=0, column='pUID', value=puidList)
```

An example is:
Dataframe I want to remove NaNs from:

```
player             team   pos_summary
NaN                NaN    NaN
Brandon Woodruff   NaN    P   
William Woods      ATL    NaN
Kyle Wright        ATL    P
```

My dataframe when I try looks like this, moving the data out of place:

```
player             team   pos_summary
Brandon Woodruff   ATL    P   
William Woods      ATL    P
Kyle Wright
```

Ideally, I want this, but no NaN rows and maintaining rows with partial NaNs:

```
player             team   pos_summary
Brandon Woodruff          P   
William Woods      ATL    
Kyle Wright        ATL    P
```

Refer to the end of the complete code to see my attempts.

Comment: From https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html, try `df.dropna(thresh=1)`? The `thresh` keyword tells pandas to "require that many non-NA values," so setting it to 1 will keep rows with at least one valid value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this to remove all NaN rows

> df.dropna(how="all")

Further, if you need to replace the NaN values with '', then use

> df.fillna('', inplace=True)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it that way, however, your data isn't accurate. You shouldn't be getting nulls in player position or team.

Secondly, if you need to parse `<table>` tags (and you don't need to pull out any attributes like a href) let `pandas` parse that table for you. It uses beautifulsoup under the hood.

```
import pandas as pd

url = r'https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/NL/2022-standard-fielding.shtml'
df = pd.read_html(url)[-1]
df = df[df['Rk'].ne('Rk')]
```

**Output:**

```
print(df[['Name', 'Tm', 'Pos Summary']])
                 Name   Tm Pos Summary
0         C.J. Abrams  SDP    SS-2B-OF
1    Ronald Acuna Jr.  ATL          OF
2        Willy Adames  MIL          SS
3        Austin Adams  SDP           P
4         Riley Adams  WSN        C-1B
..                ...  ...         ...
509     Miguel Yajure  PIT           P
510  Mike Yastrzemski  SFG          OF
511  Christian Yelich  MIL          OF
512        Juan Yepez  STL          OF
513      Huascar Ynoa  ATL           P

[495 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Oh, I had no idea that this was even possible. I'll have to read into this more. Thank you!

Comment: YA the reason you are getting nulls is because your logic is off. I would try not to create lists of each column, put rather create a list of each row in the table, and use a dictionary to match that to the correct columns. That will alleviate the issue the rows not lining up correctly.